# How to run foundry in debug/trace mode (NOT the solidity)

Tags: foundry

I'm running into an issue with foundry and I want to see the rust output (aka, I want to run it in debug mode).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run foundry with `RUST_LOG=debug`.

ie:

```
RUST_LOG=debug forge build
```